# Alternate way to use String.Split

Tags: c#, linq

The below code looks in a string composed of emails seperated by commas and adds an email if it isnt already in the result collection which is also of type string.

```
string [] oEmails=orderEmails.Split(',');
string[] partEmails= part[Constants.Emails].ToString().Split(','); 
foreach(string email in oEmails)
{
  if(!partEmails.Contains(email))
  {
      part[Constants.Emails] += "," + email;
  }
}
```

Is this the best approach to write this logic? I works fine, but I was wondering maybe if there is a way I can consolidate this logic into a lambda expression?

What bothers me is I am doing nothing with these arrays but splitting the input string. They serve no other purpose.

Comment: What are you going to be doing with the array? It is not clear what you are trying to achieve, so a recommendation is difficult to come by...

Comment: nothing but splitting the input string. That is why I dont like this

Comment: But you are doing much more. For what end are you splitting the array?

Comment: And why are you using `string[]` instead of `List<string>`?

Comment: The emails come in as a string serperated by commas. The result is another string seperated by commas. I put them the input and the result strings into arrays only to be able to easily manipulate the strings..(i.e. use Contains)

Comment: I tried List<string> but couldnt get it to cast correctly

Comment: What would be your suggestion?

Comment: Are you simply trying to remove duplicates from a comma separated list of emails?

Comment: Again, without understanding what you are trying to achieve, I can't suggest anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
part[Constants.Emails] =
 string.Join(",", part[Constants.Emails].Split(',').Union(orderEmails.Split(',')).ToArray());
```

Besides that, you are storing the emails the wrong way. Don't store them as a comma separated string, store them as a List. That way you don't have to parse them every time you modify the "collection".

Comment: This is the cleanest solution out of all of them, I think. It avoids any unnecessary checks, but you still have to account for duplicates based on cAsInG. `Union` allows you to specify a comparer, so you can provide it one of the many `StringComparer` instances.

Answer (score 3):

Can you use a `HashSet` instead of a single large `string`?  This will only add a value to the list if it does not already exist in the list.  E.g.

```
part[Constants.Emails] = new HashSet<string>();
foreach (var email in oEmails)
    part[Constants.Emails].Add(email);
```

If you need easier conversions to/from one large string, you can make a class, e.g.

```
class Emails : HashSet<string>
{
    public Emails(string concatenatedList)
        : base(concatenatedList.Split(','))
    {
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Join(",", this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Agreed, this is one of the few approaches that didn't immediately jump to LINQ and yet utilizes built-in types in an easy/efficient manner.

Answer (score 0):

```
part[Constant.Emails] += oEmails.Where(email => !partEmails.Contains(email))
                                .Aggregate(b, (current, email)
                                              => current + ("," + email));
```

First, this selects the emails that aren't in there yet (first line) then it aggregates them into a string of a few `,mail` parts (second and third line). Then it adds that back to the string (first line).

Comment: What about if you have otheremailaddress@host.com in the list and try to add emailaddress@host.com?  It will see that "emailaddress@host.com" is already in the list, because that's a substring of "otheremailaddress@host.com" and decide that it doesn't need to add it.

Comment: @TimS.: You are the second one to remark this. Note that this is `List.Contains` and that this is not `String.Contains`. This is an exact reproduction from the OPs approach, and has actually been converted from the one to the other with ReSharper.

Comment: Oops, my mistake.  I'll leave my comment so others can see your response to it.

Answer (score 0):

This way avoids you the `part[Constants.Emails].Split(',')` by performing lookups directly within the string:

```
string[] oEmails = orderEmails.Split(',');
string partEmails = part[Constants.Emails];

foreach (string email in oEmails)
{
    bool index = partEmails.IndexOf(email);
    bool isAlreadyPresent = index != -1 && 
        (index == 0 || partEmails[index - 1] == ',') &&
        (index + email.Length == partEmails.Length || partEmails[index + 1] == ',');

    if (!isAlreadyPresent)
    {
        partEmails += "," + email;
    }
}

part[Constants.Emails] = partEmails;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
part[Constants.Emails] = string.Join( ",", ( 
    from e in (part[Constants.Emails].ToString() + "," +  orderEmails).Split(',')
    where !string.IsNullOrEmpty( e )
    select e 
).Distinct().ToArray() );
```

It's less readable, but likely runs much faster.

**EDIT:** Most other solutions (including the question) use string concatination.  StringBuilder is much, much better for this.

**EDIT:** Storing this data as List or a hash table is much better than concatinating the resulting array/list into a comma-delimited string and parsing it back out every time, say nothing to getting the wrong answer if one of your strings had a legitimate comma in it.

Comment: Why would it be faster, especially when using `Distinct`?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to consolidate the logic like this:

```
oEmails.Where(partEmails.Contains).Select(e => partEmails[Constants.Emails] += string.Format(",{0}", e));
```

Comment: If I'm adding "foo@bar.com" and there's already "irrelevant-foo@bar.commando", then "foo@bar.com" won't get added.

Comment: @robrich: Not true, because this is `List.Contains` instead of `String.Contains`; I'm amazed that three persons made this reading mistake so far. :D

Comment: @robrich: Tom is right. This will do a full match on items in the list. If you were the downvoter, I would appreciate it if you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try

```
var result = oEmails.Select((x, i) => oEmails[i] == partEmails[i] ? part[Constants.Emails] :
             partEmails.Contains(x) ? part[Constants.Emails] : -1).ToArray();
```